# PHP Ocultar Menu Por Rol MySQL

Tags: php, sesiones

Tengo una sesión que se basa por el IdRol de una base de datos, dependiendo el Rol muestra el menu, pero solo me deja poner 1 Rol por Menu y no me deja por 2. (No quiero usar un if anidado por que tengo 8 tipos de usuario y haría un mega código grandísimo)
Ejemplo que si funciona con 1 solo IdRol:

```
                <? if ($_SESSION[ 'idRol' ] == 1) { ?>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="index.php#" title="Subtipo" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu">
                        <span class="item-text">Subtipo</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav collapse ">
                        <li>
                            <a href="Subtipo.php" title="Subtipo Nuevo" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu">
                                <span class="item-text">Subtipo Nuevo</span>
                            </a>                                                     
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <? } ?>
```

Cuando lo intento con dos no me deja, ejemplo:

```
                <? if ($_SESSION[ 'idRol' ] == 1 && $_SESSION[ 'idRol' ] == 2) { ?>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="index.php#" title="Subtipo" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu">
                        <span class="item-text">Subtipo</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav collapse ">
                        <li>
                            <a href="Subtipo.php" title="Subtipo Nuevo" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu">
                                <span class="item-text">Subtipo Nuevo</span>
                            </a>                                                     
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <? } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error esta en el IF le estas diciendo que `$_SESSION['idRol'] == 1` y que al mismo tiempo sea igual  a 2 lo cuál no es posible creo que deberías de cambiar por un OR.

```
if ($_SESSION[ 'idRol' ] == 1 || $_SESSION[ 'idRol' ] == 2)
```

De esta forma entrara al IF siempre que la variable tenga el **valor de 1 ó 2**

**UPDATE**

Para validar varios ID'S puedes crear un arreglo que contenga todos tu Id de Rol validos y preguntar si el Id de Session se encuentra dentro de este.

```
$id_validos = array(1,2,3,4);
if (in_array($_SESSION['idRol'],$id_validos))
```

Ó

También puedes preguntar si el Id es mayor o igual a tu limite inferior de ID y si es menor o igual al limite superior de tu rango de ID's

```
if($_SESSION['idRol'] >= 1 && $_SESSION['idRol'] <= 4)
```

Comment: me funciona, hay alguna condicional de por ejemplo: $_SESSION[ 'idRol' ] == 1 "hasta" $_SESSION[ 'idRol' ] == 4

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta.